# linux C struct buffer from serial

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

How to properly struct a buffer from serial.

```
int serialCheckforBuffer (int fd)
{
  int result ;
  if (ioctl (fd, FIONREAD, &result) == -1)
  return -1 ;
  return result ;
}

int serialGetchar (int fd)
{
  uint8_t x ;
  if (read (fd, &x, 1) != 1)
  return -1 ;
  return ((int)x) & 0xFF ;
}
```

And I am reading that like this

```
for (;;)
{

    while (serialCheckforBuffer (fd))
     {
      printf ("%02X", serialGetchar(fd));
      fflush (stdout) ;
     }
     usleep(10000);
}
```

The output result is "071E00000118"

How can I struct my readed buffer to suit like this

```
    struct obj_Properties
    {
       int Type;
       int ID;
       int Index;
       unsigned int msb;
       unsigned int lsb;
       int chksum;
    };
```

So if I read it again that will be in this format

```
   struct obj_Properties prop;
   printf ("%02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X", prop.Type, prop.ID, prop.Index, prop.msb,    prop.lsb, prop.chksum);
```

I tried code but no success.
Maybe I'm missing something.

```
  void buildBuffer(struct obj_Properties *buffer)
  {
     while((serialCheckforBuffer(fd)) == -1)
     usleep(1000);
     memcpy(buffer, &sBuffer, sizeof(struct obj_Properties));
  }
```

Comment: How do you know you have received `sizeof(struct obj_Properties)` bytes in serial buffer before coping it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop, don't loop through printing out the values, assign them instead:

```
prop.Type = serialGetchar(fd));
prop.ID = serialGetchar(fd));
prop.Index = serialGetchar(fd));
prop.msb = serialGetchar(fd));
prop.lsb = serialGetchar(fd));
prop.chksum = serialGetchar(fd));
printf ("%02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X", prop.Type, prop.ID, prop.Index, prop.msb,    prop.lsb, prop.chksum);
```